# Only I can see my output from custom slash commands

Tags: slack-api, slack

I created a custom slash command in Slack.  The backend code, not that it's important, is a Lambda function in Python in AWS.

My problem is that when I enter the slash command, I am the only one who can see the message.  Otherwise, it works perfectly.  Is there a way to get others to see the output from my custom slash command?

Answer (score 21):

See "'In Channel' vs. 'Ephemeral' responses" here: https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command.

> By default, the response messages sent to commands will only be
>   visible to the user that issued the command (we call these "ephemeral"
>   messages). However, if you would like the response to be visible to
>   all members of the channel in which the user typed the command, you
>   can add a `response_type` of `in_channel` to the JSON response, like this:
>
> ```
> {
>     "response_type": "in_channel",
>     "text": "It's 80 degrees right now.",
>     "attachments": [
>         {
>             "text":"Partly cloudy today and tomorrow"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> When the `response_type` is `in_channel`, both the response message and the initial message typed by the user will be shared in
>   the channel.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a block in your JSON payload to slack (you used [slacks block-kit](https://api.slack.com/block-kit)) e.g

```
`"blocks": []`
```

you'll have to put the `"response_type": "in_channel"` above `blocks` for it to work :) e.g

```
{
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "blocks": [....]
}
```